# Problema al enviar datos del formulario con Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax, bootstrap-4

Amigos por favor me ayudarían a identificar mi problema estoy usando ajax para enviar los datos que extraigo del formulario, no se si son las librerias las estoy llamando mal? ó es la estructura del ajax, alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?. Gracias.

Mis librerias dentro del head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Recursos/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Recursos/css/styles_2.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Mis librerias abajo del antes de cerrar la etiqueta body

```
<script src="../Recursos/js/jquery-3.3.1.js "> </script>
    <script src="../Recursos/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="../Recursos/js/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="../Recursos/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Y por ultimo agrego mis funciones.js

```
<script src="Scripts/validar_form.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/enviar_data_form.js"></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/functions.js"></script>
```

Mi ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"localhost/Proyecto_AIUP/Ubicacion/Verificacion/Validar_Entrada.php",
            data:{ matricula:js_matricula, nombre:js_nombre, apellido_pa:js_apellido_pa, apellido_ma:js_apellido_ma, id_carrera: js_carrera},
            dataType:"jsonp",
            jsonp:"jsoncallback",
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
              if(data.estado=="insertado"){
                  alert("Muy bien");
                }else{
                  alert("Por favor inserte datos validos.");
                }
            }
      });
          return false;
    };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esto al final del .php:

```
if($sentencia->execute()){
        $id= $sentencia->insert_id;
        $datos["estado"] = "insertado";
        $datos["Id"] = $id;
        //printf ("Nuevo registro con el id %d.\n", $sentencia->insert_id);


        //$totalInsert=$sentencia->affected_rows;  
        //$mensaje=($totalInsert > 0) ? "Se ha insertado correctamente" : "No fue posible la inserción. Error: ".$sentencia->error;  
        //$arrResult['mensaje'] = $mensaje;
        header("location: ../Cuestionario/cuestionario.php");
        include_once('../Cuestionario/cuestionario.php');


    }else{

        $datos["estado"] = "error";
        $datos["Id"] = null;
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conexion->close();

    $resultadoJson = json_encode($datos);
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadoJson . ');';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y porque me aparece el id arriba en el buscador cuando envio datos del formulario???
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la URL esto se repite dos veces: `localhost/Proyecto_AIUP/Ubicacion/localhost/Proyecto_AIUP/Ubicacion/`  no sé si tienes redirecciones o algo extraño en el servidor que te está creando una URL errónea...

Comment: No entiendo cómo pasa eso de repetidos? OK ya vi el error de que se repiten pero no se cómo se origina eso.

Comment: En la primera imagen que muestras, si te fijas en el último `GET`, que es precisamente el que está dando un error 404 muestra que la URL se está creando con esa parte repetida dos veces. En Ajax parece correcta, puesto que el valor que pasas como URL es este:  `url:"localhost/Proyecto_AIUP/Ubicacion/Verificacion/Validar_Entrada.php"` pero luego algo pasa en el servidor que la parte `localhost/Proyecto_AIUP/Ubicacion/Verificacion/` se repite dos veces. Eso suena a un problema de redirección en el servidor.

Comment: No sé si tienes un archivo `.htaccess` en la carpeta `Verificacion` o en otra de las carpetas: `Ubicacion`  o `Proyecto_AIUP`  o  en el `localhost` ... que haga alguna redirección extraña. Eso es lo que parece, no veo otro motivo.

Comment: No tengo ningun .htaccess lo que tengo dentro del php al comienzo es esto:  header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
 header("Access-Control-All-Origin: *");

Comment: deberias poner rutas absolutas, ejemplo si estas dentro de la misma carpta, entonces solo el nombre del archvo Validar_Entrada.php si esta en una carpta en la misma gerarquia seria carpeta/Validar_Entrada.php y si esta en una carpetas atras ../Validar_Entrada.php

Comment: No le veo sentido al menos al header relativo a `Content-Type`. El archivo PHP que usas con Ajax es sólo un archivo de gestión de recursos, ese content type no tiene absolutamente ningún sentido ahí.

Comment: puesto que la dirección usada es relativa `url:"localhost/Proyecto_AIUP/Ubicacion/Verificacion/Validar_Entrada.php"` es posible que se esté duplicando por efecto de `basepath` si usas una dirección absoluta como indica @srJJ debiera resolverse.

Comment: Amigo ya resolví el problema gracias, pero me apareció. Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Ya lo resolví amigos gracias por todo hasta pronto uff que quebradero de cabeza. ejjeje :| :)

Comment: Al menos di cómo lo resolviste. Otro usuario puede verse con un problema parecido y en ese caso la solución podría servirle también a él.